# Fragment did not create a view after rotating device

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to make a 2 fragments screen in the tablet view but it's crashing after rotating the device.
This is `layout-sw600dp/`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.morxander.popularmovies.MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
        android:name="com.morxander.popularmovies.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/movie_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the related part of the code :

```
    private static boolean mTwoPane;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (findViewById(R.id.movie_detail_container) != null) {
        mTwoPane = true;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_main, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
        }else{
            mTwoPane = false;
        }
    }

}
.....
.....
.....
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // Method to set the views controls
        initComponents(rootView);
        return rootView;
```

And when I rotate the device the app crashes and gives me the following error :

```
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338): Process: com.morxander.popularmovies, PID: 4338
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.morxander.popularmovies/com.morxander.popularmovies.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3912)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:144)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at com.morxander.popularmovies.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     ... 11 more
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.morxander.popularmovies.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment did not create a view.
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2199)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreateView(ActionBarActivity.java:543)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
08-10 21:22:34.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4338):     ... 21 more
    }
```

I tried many solutions but nothing is working for me.

Comment: have u saved the state in onSaveInstanceState

Comment: You cannot perform fragment transaction to fragment added from XML.

Comment: @ArunShankar I have been told the same but i don't know how to use that.

Comment: @Milanix so what I shall do?

Comment: First thing change fragment_main in your xml to a FrameLayout.

Comment: ya @Milanix is right, for dynamic fragment transaction, you must use FrameLayout, then double check both framelayout id's are same.

Comment: I will usually do something like this inside your fragment setRetainInstance(!mTwoPane), otherwise you will get an exception because after rotating from landscape (multi-pane) to portrait (single-pane), the container that fragment was originally attached won't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the layout passed in the statement

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

Comment: I know that this line is the problem but it's working .. It fails only when changing the orientation.